# Big O's on bases less than 1

Tags: computational-complexity, asymptotics, computer-science

I have a function $f(x) = x^3 + .92^x$. I would assume that it is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ because $.92^x$ exponentially decays as $x$ grows and $x^3$ continually grows, but it is $\mathcal{O}(.92^x)$. I'm not entirely sure why. I would get it if the base was greater than $1$, because obviously an exponential grows faster than a cubic, but it isn't.

Comment: $0.92^x$ is technically $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$ as $x \to +\infty$, though that is a rather uselessly imprecise statement.

Comment: Assuming that $\mathcal O(\cdot)$ means "as $x \to \infty$", you are right:  it *is* $\mathcal O(x^3)$, and it is *not* $\mathcal O(0.92^x)$.

Comment: @LSpice It is also true that $0.92^x$ is $\mathcal{O}(0.92^x)$, though that's again a rather trivial statement (any function will be $\mathcal{O}$ of itself).

Comment: @Ian, certainly I [agree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855904/big-os-on-bases-less-than-1#comment7954614_3855904), but "it" in [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855904/big-os-on-bases-less-than-1#comment7954536_3855904) is $x^3 + 0.92^x$, not just $0.92^x$.  That is, I might better have said "$x^3 + 0.92^x$ is $\mathcal O(x^3)$ as $x \to \infty$, not $\mathcal O(0.92^x)$ as $x \to \infty$."

Comment: @LSpice Oh I am sorry, I misread the question. Yes, you have it right (and your pronoun usage wasn't confusing or anything).

Comment: You state "*but it is O(.92^x)*", but don't say *why* you say this.  I.e. who or what told you that was the answer?